# DNA sequence random sampling

Tags: python, bioinformatics

I would like to create say a 1000 random groups using 100 DNA sequences. I have text file (sequence.txt) containing 100 fasta sequences, and i want subgroups containing 10 fasta sequence chosen at random for further analysis. here is the code that i tried and i have been getting some errors.

```
import random
import re
f = open("sequence.txt", "r")
lf = f.split(">")
lf.pop(0)
f.close()
for i in range(10):
    sublist = "subset_%s.fas" % i
    random_group = random.randrange(len("sequence.txt"), 10)
    output = open(sublist, "w")
    for m in random_group:
        sequence = ">" + lf[m]
        output.write(sequence)
    output.close()
```

Answer (score 4):

Check out [`random.sample`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html#random.sample). It lets you sample `k` (in your case `k=10`) elements from a sequence (in your case `lf`):

```
>>> import random
>>> sequences = range(100)
>>> for i in range(1000):
...     # Sample a random group
...     random_group = random.sample( lf, 10 )

        # Output group
        ...
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not using `random.randrange` correctly: `random.randrange(start, stop[, step])`. If you supply two values, they becomes `start` and `stop`. Your `len("sequence.txt")` is larger than 10 already (12).

Why `len("sequence.txt")` not `len(lf)`? `len("sequence.txt")` just gives you the length of the `string`.

`[random.randrange(0, len(lf)) for i in range(10)]` should be what you want, or use `random.sample`

Comment: thanks, i will try out the codes suggested. Is there a way to find sampling size for efficient analysis?

Comment: That's difficult to say. Depends on what you are doing. Phylogeny reconstruction? Estimating sequence polymorphism? Estimating LD? Really depends.

Comment: say for motif analysis

Comment: I see. Chipseq result? Still depends. Depends on how strong the pattern is. Large sample size=better detection power. Small sample size=less detection power. BTW, if you are not doing bootstrapping, for your application sampling without replacement should be more suitable (that's what `sample` is for).